# C# XML) How to get values within specific tag?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, tags

I tried ways like below but they're not working showing NullReferenceException. It seemed easy but some solutions with LINQ look complicated because I'm not familiar with LINQ and XML parsing.

I only want values as B1, B2, B3 and C1, C2..... within R1.(There're also R2, R3..so on.)

What I've tried are,

```
string greenvalue = objDoc.Descendants("R1").First().Element("B1").Value.ToString();
```

and

```
string bluevalue = objDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ITEM[R1]").Element("B1").Value.ToString();
```

XML code is as below,

```
-<RESULT>
   -<ITEM>
      -<R1>
         -<B DESC="product">
             <B1> chocolate </B1>
             <B2> white </B2>
             <B3> Kisses </B3>
             <B4> bar type </B4>
             <B5> 2 $ </B5>
             <B6>2014-09-26 </B6>
             <B7>201404418 </B7>
          </B>
         -<C DESC="ingredient">
            -<CR1>
                <C1>cacao paste </C1>
                <C2> concentrated </C2>
                <C3> 21.69 </C3>
                <C4> gram </C4>
            </CR1>
         </C>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted codes didn't work because `<B1>` is not direct child of `<R1>`. There is `<B>` element in between which you need to consider.

> *"I only want values as B1, B2, B3 and C1, C2..... within R1"*

This is one possible way :

```
string bluevalue = (string)objDoc.XPathSelectElement("//R1/B/B1");
```

or the equivalent LINQ without XPath :

```
string greenvalue = (string)objDoc.Descendants("R1")
                                  .Elements("B")
                                  .Elements("B1")
                                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Oh..Thank you so much ! The first one works fine. I've tried couples of hours but couldn't find suitable one with my case. Thank you for your excellent knowldege and support !

Comment: Can you please help me just little more..? I need to get the C1 value as well but (string)objDoc.XPathSelectElement("//R1/C/CR1/C1").Value; doesn't work..with NullReferenceException..I'm really not familiar with XML structure and depressed..Please kindly advise me once again..

Comment: That XPath should work for the XML posted in question. Given that it didn't work, that means the structure of your *actual* XML is different. In this case, please open new question, post sample XML and code snippet to reproduce the problem. Thanks

Comment: ok, please wait 30 minutes. I'll open a new question and post all the XML. To my knowledge, it's just same..oh, my goodness !

Comment: @KayLee Sure, let me know if you have posted one. Here is an example of *minimal but complete* codes that, in this case, demonstrate how I couldn't reproduce the problem using XML in this question

Comment: Hello, I've solved to get the values through XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes way. Many thanks again for your kind support !

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is to parse the xml file into C# using XmlDocument class. then u can refer the xml tags one by one.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); // load document
doc.Load(Path);
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("R1")
```

Then you can access the nodes and values inside R1.

```
nodeList[i].ParentNode.Name
nodeList[i].ChildNodes[x].InnerText
nodeList[i].ChildNodes[x].Attributes["Id"].Value
```

Comment: I know how to load XDocument and I appreciate your excellent knowledge and support. However, another person provided right answer earlier. Thank you !